# Why console app can't read App.config , if run from azure web jobs?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

This is my console app:
[image]

Program.cs:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string test = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BatFile"];                
                string log = @"D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous\ConsoleApp1\log.txt";
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(log))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(test);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string log = @"D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous\ConsoleApp1\log.txt";
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(log))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(ex.ToString ());
                }
            }
            


        }
    }
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="BatFile" value="DB/Sample.bat"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Result can't get setting from `App.config` file when run azure webjobs:

[image]

If i run at local, it is ok.
Why console app can't read App.config , if run from azure web jobs?

Comment: My answer, is it what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use (.Net Framework 4.5 +)

```
string sValue = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BatFile"];
```

not

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BatFile"];
```

It works for me.

[image]

My test code.

[image]

Comment: I try but it still not ok. What is your Version of Net FW? Do you add "using System.Configuration;"?

Comment: @DT Re-creating a demo console app (.net framework 4.7.2), and then publishing a new one, should solve the problem.

Comment: @DT Following your steps, when I reproduced your problem, I also encountered your current problem. It may be that some packages were installed in the program. Specifically, I did not troubleshoot and re-created the project to solve the problem.

Comment: @DT You can check my test code. https://github.com/Jason446620/ConsoleReadAppconfig

Comment: @DT `.net framework 4.7.2`.  Azure web app runs in a sandbox environment. If it is not for special project reasons, I suggest that the webjob version can use the higher version of .net framework or .net 5, which is not related to the framework used by webapp. The sandbox supports all versions of webjob in .net by default. (If I remember correctly. The only limitation I found is that VS cannot directly publish webjobs of .net core)

Comment: Thank your, your help. The cause : I using FW 3.5, If i upgrade project to 4.5, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BatFile"];  return ok.